# Hooking up incremental encoder to mbed

Tags: encoder, mbed

I've spent the last hour trying to get an incremental encoder working with an mbed module.

**Keyes KY-040 Rotary Encoder** 
https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B079H3C98M/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o06_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

**LPC1768 mbed module** 
[os.mbed.com/platforms/mbed-LPC1768](http://os.mbed.com/platforms/mbed-LPC1768)

The code I've written is as follows:

```
    #include "QEI.h"

Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);
//Use X4 encoding.
//QEI wheel(p29, p30, NC, 624, QEI::X4_ENCODING);
//Use X2 encoding by default.
QEI wheel (p5, p6, NC, 20);
DigitalOut led1(LED1);
DigitalOut led2(LED2);
DigitalOut led3(LED3);
DigitalOut led4(LED4);

int main() {
int x;
led1 = 0;
led2 = 0;
led3 = 0;
led4 = 0;

    while(1){
        x = wheel.getPulses() % 4;

        if (x == 0){
            led1 = 1;
            led2 = 0;
            led3 = 0;
            led4 = 0;
        } else if (x == 1) {
            led1 = 0;
            led2 = 1;
            led3 = 0;
            led4 = 0;
        } else if (x == 2) {
            led1 = 0;
            led2 = 0;
            led3 = 1;
            led4 = 0;
        } else if (x == 3) {
            led1 = 0;
            led2 = 0;
            led3 = 0;
            led4 = 1;
        }    
    }

}
```

I've tried both pull up and pull down resistors on the lines, but the mbed is not showing any sign of processing these. In all likeliness, I've made a wiring mistake.

Does anyone have a schematic I can follow on how to hook it up correctly?

Comment: What mbed board or components are you using?

Comment: Have you confirmed, with a voltmeter, that the voltage levels on the mbed inputs are changing from low-to-high (and back) as you turn the encoder?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone have a schematic I can follow on how to hook it up
>   correctly?

#### According to:

http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-sensors-and-input/keyes-ky-040-arduino-rotary-encoder-user-manual/

- "+" is supply Voltage
- "CLK" is Encoder Output A (with an included pullup R of 10k to "+" on the pcb)
- "DT" is Encoder Output B (with an included pullup R of 10k to "+" on the pcb)
- "GND" connects to both Encoder Output Common, and one leg of the
  push-button switch.
- "SW" is the other leg of the push-button switch.

*This next image is from the same website:*
[image: http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-sensors-and-input/keyes-ky-040-arduino-rotary-encoder-user-manual/]
<sup>http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-sensors-and-input/keyes-ky-040-arduino-rotary-encoder-user-manual/</sup>

The encoder is a typical quadrature style encoder with a an additional push-button in the knob stem.

#### So:

- Connect 5V (or your existing system voltage) to the "+" input.
- Connect your system ground to the "Gnd" terminal.
- Connect the "CLK" terminal to one digital input.
- Connect the "DT" terminal to the other digital input.

Confirm its all working with a voltmeter, then start writing code.

#### CLK and DT wavforms (image from the same web site noted above).

On the plot:

- C = Ground
- A = CLK
- B = DT
- "Open" = 5V output (measured with voltmeter).
- "Closed" = 0V output (measured with voltmeter).

[image]

<sup>http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-sensors-and-input/keyes-ky-040-arduino-rotary-encoder-user-manual/</sup>

The dotted lines show where the switch detents should be (however, I can't confirm this without having the actual encoder in hand).  What this means is that when you turn the encoder, and it 'clicks', the encoder is designed to stop between clicks at these locations.  Sometimes one 'click' is many counts.  This depends on the encoder's mechanical design (how the detents mechanically line up with the output electrical changes), and the decoding algorithm.  If you get more than 1 count per click, then divide the output in software.

#### Some notes:

- The labeling of the PCB seems silly.
- There are things that you'll learn about interfacing mechanical switches to micro-controllers that may surprise you.  Research this.  Check compatibility with the "QEI" module you use - as I am not familiar with it.
- For troubleshooting, I'd recommend that you define in your code these variables: CurrentCount, PreviousCount, DividedCount (%), Direction (CurrentCount - PreviousCount).

Comment: Oddly, the other schematic on that page shows no pull up resistors when connected to an Arduino. Are they actually needed?

Comment: The pull-up resistors are included on the encoder pcb.  You do not need to add them.  They're not shown in the second schematic because that schematic shows how to connect the encoder *PCB* to an Arduino, and the PCB already has the resistors installed.

Comment: Ahh, ok. I've made the connections you listed, and the mbed seems to be responding. However, 1 turn of the encoder seems to move the lit led by 2, and sometimes not at all. Does my code look sound to you?

I also noted when using a voltmeter that as I turned the encoder, the measured. voltage remained at 5v

Comment: I suspect the double movement might have something to do with the X2 encoding. Still doesn't explain the missed counts.

I should point out that I measured voltage from the CLK output to ground.

Comment: > "voltage remained at 5v... ...measured voltage from the CLK output to ground."    - Well, that's not right.  Both CLK and DT should have waveforms like shown above (edited answer).  After looking at the QEI code, I think that you should use X4 encoding.  What mbed board are you using?

Comment: https://os.mbed.com/platforms/mbed-LPC1768/

Comment: Wouldn't X4 encoding mean that the LED would move 4 places per twist of the encoder knob?

Comment: Possibly (depending on how the encoder & detents are constructed).  But it's better to capture every edge of the encoder transitions in order not to miss counts and detect change in direction reliably.  If this is a slow-speed application (a human turning a knob), then you will probably be fine with X2.  If you want to make it as good as you can, use X4.  From my experience: you will end up using X4.

Comment: For this particular application, where one twist should equal 1 encoder count, wouldn't X1 encoding be all that's needed (and preferable)? I don't see why you would want to double or quadruple the resolution.

Comment: Can you explain the constant 5V signal on the CLK line? I wonder whether the high impedance of the input pin is needed for the 5V/0V swing.

Comment: >"Can you explain the constant 5V signal on the CLK line?": No.  Probable wiring issue.  "I wonder whether the high impedance of the input pin is needed for the 5V/0V swing.": Pin configuration of the mbed inputs should be handled by the QEI module.  However, I have never used this module, and you will need to determine if any additional config needs to be done.

Comment: "I don't see why you would want to double or quadruple the resolution.": The point is not to increase resolution.  The point is to not miss events (like a change in direction, or counts).  Missing events can lead to strange behavior (like counting down when it should count up).  The different encoding specifies how teh intputs are treated (as interrupts or not).  I think that you need to read teh QEI code.  Better yet, try writing the encoder handler yourself, first without interrupts, then with.  After that, you will be an expert.

Comment: Ok, but X4 would quadruple the counts, right? So I would have to divide the count by 4?

Comment: >"but X4 would quadruple the counts, right?" Probably.  This is great  if you're doing position feedback.  For human-knob-turning, right-shift by 2 is very efficient (counts>>2).   ;~)